# MPAndroidChart - how to view only few data at once

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have problem like in a title, im looking for solution, how to show few data at once.
[image]
For example, right now at x axis data from 1 to 31, and i want to see only 10? To see the rest user will have to swipe Chart.

I was trying to do it with

```
barChart.setVisibleXRange(1, 10);
```

but then the few first data ar invisible, but i can still click at them, after swipe, are visible. 
[image]
[image]

Here is a code of BarChart

```java
 private  void BarChart()
    {

        BarDataSet bardataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "Wartości");
        bardataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        BarData data = new BarData();
        data.addDataSet(bardataset);
        data.setValueTextSize(12f);


        barChart.setData(data);
        barChart.getDescription().setText("Liczba zamówień");
        barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
        barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        barChart.getXAxis().setSpaceMax(3f);
        barChart.setVisibleXRange(1, 10);
        YAxis y = barChart.getAxisLeft();
        YAxis y2 = barChart.getAxisLeft();
        y.setAxisMinimum(0);
        y2.setAxisMinimum(0);
        y.setLabelCount(6);
        y2.setLabelCount(6);

        barChart.animateY(1500);
    }
```

Bar DataSet :

```
x = 14 y = 4
x = 1 y = 0
x = 2 y = 44
x = 3 y = 0
x = 4 y = 18
x = 5 y = 43
x = 6 y = 10
x = 7 y = 16
x = 8 y = 11
x = 9 y = 0
x = 10 y = 0
x = 11 y = 14
x = 12 y = 0
x = 13 y = 0
x = 15 y = 0
x = 16 y = 0
x = 17 y = 0
x = 18 y = 0
x = 19 y = 0
x = 20 y = 0
x = 21 y = 0
x = 22 y = 0
x = 23 y = 0
x = 24 y = 0
x = 25 y = 0
x = 26 y = 0
x = 27 y = 0
x = 28 y = 0
x = 29 y = 0
x = 30 y = 0
```

Thanks for any solutions and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [doc](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport):

```
chart.setData(data);// need to set data first
.....
chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10F); // allow 10 values 
chart.moveViewToX(0F); // start position 0
```

Comment: It begins here, https://imgur.com/YCv1kZM
but after swiping to the begining few data are still invisible
https://imgur.com/1lz1CyV

Comment: y = 0 , how can it be seen

Comment: at 2nd screenshoot there is selected x = 2 , and there y = 42, but if i will unselect it, than becomes invisible

Comment: you should use chart.moveViewToX(0F);